# How to get fully quallified domain name of a hp-ux machine?

Tags: hostname, hp-ux

How to get full qualified domain name of a HP-UX machine as like of `hostname -f` in linux?

From man pages, `hostname` command has no options.

I could get fqdn by reading the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, but is it the correct way to do, or do i have to execute a `nslookup` command.

```
bash-4.2# cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain csez.abccor.com
nameserver 192.68.5.11
bash-4.2# cat /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}' | head -1
csez.abccorp.com
```

Also, is the below method is correct ?

```
echo "$(echo `hostname`).$(cat /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}' | head -1)"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nslookup "$(hostname)" | awk 'BEGIN {rv=1;} /^Name:/ {print $2; exit rv=0;} END {exit rv;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

> Also, is the below method is correct ?

Better to use this one:

```
echo "$(echo `hostname`).$(grep domain /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}' | head -1)"
```